# WPF ComboBox - ItemTemplate vs. IsEditable

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml

I created a combo box with an item template. The template includes a status icon and text:

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
      <WrapPanel>
        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding StateImage}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Address}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
      </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

<ComboBox x:Name="CbxClients" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Width="320" Height="24" IsEditable="False" />
```

Now I want to make the the combo box editable, so that the user can enter new strings, which hould then be added to the list. Thus I set "IsEditable" to true. This is the result:

[image]

This change causes a problem: the icon is now no longer shown in the combo box (only in the drop down area). While editing/entering a string this would be fine, but after the input has been committed, I would expect the new item being added to the list and an icon to be shown.

Is there any way I can achieve this behavior?

Comment: Where/how is the ComboBox populated? Where/how do you bind the selected value?

Comment: @SanchoPanza That's a simple CbxClients.ItemsSource = new ObservalbleCollection<MyItemType>(); After that I add instances of MyItemType to the collection.

Comment: Then the answer to your question is simple: within the DropDownClosedEvent, create a new List from the ItemsSource, add the new value to it and reassign the list to ItemsSource. Side-note: using the MVVM pattern instead of code-behind would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering two problems:

1. **Problem:** The `ComboBox` is not containing simple `string` items. Instead you have defined a `DataTemplate` to render a more complex item model.
   **Solution:** The point is that the `ComboBox` has no chance to know how to use the input value to construct a new instance of the item model. You have to do it explicitly.
2. **Problem:** Because your `ComboBox` is configured to be in edit mode, the TextBox will only contain a text representation of your item model (the `ComboBox` will call `object.ToString` on the model to obtain a text representation).
   **Solution:** There is no out-of-the-box solution. If `ComboBox.IsEditable` returns `false` the `ComboBox` will display the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` using a `ContentPresenter`. If `ComboBox.IsEditable` returns `true` the `ComboBox` will replace the `ContentPresenter` with a `TextBox` in order to allow the editing. You can now override the original `ControlTemplate` and toggle between both content sites. For example, on `GotFocus` you show the `TextBox` and on `LostFocus` you switch back to the `ContentPresenter`.
   You can use the XAML Designer to extract the `ControlTemplate` or use visit [Microsoft Dos: ComboBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and copy the template and references from there.

To enable text search set `ComboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled` to `true` and set the attached property `TextSearch.TextPath` to the actual property on the item model.

For performance reasons you should replace the `Label` with a `TextBlock`, especially when the displayed text is dynamic.

Given is the following item model:

```cs
class NetworkAddress : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ImageSource StateImage { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

To enable searching and item creation you must configure the `ComboBox` as follows:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkAddresses}"
          IsEditable="True"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Address"
          PreviewKeyUp="ComboBox_PreviewKeyUp">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type NetworkAddress}">
      <WrapPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding StateImage}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
      </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Then handle the the `ComboBox.PreviewKeyUp` event to add a new item:

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  // TODO::Property must be a dependency property because MainWindow is a DependencyObject
  public ObservableCollection<NetworkAddress> NetworkAddresses { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
    this.NetworkAddresses = new ObservableCollection<NetworkAddress>
    {
      new NetworkAddress() { ... },
      new NetworkAddress() { ... },
    };
  }

  private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Key is not Key.Enter or not Key.Return)
    {
      return;
    }

    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    string inputText = comboBox.Text;
    if (comboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled
        && comboBox.SelectedItem is null
      || !this.NetworkAddresse.Any(address => address.Address.Equals(inputText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
      AddNewItemToCollection(inputText);;
      comboBox.SelectedIndex = comboBox.Items.Count - 1;

      // Refresh is only required for the ComboBox flyout to render properly
      comboBox.Items.Refresh();
    }
  }

  private void AddNewItemToCollection(string text) 
    => this.NetworksAddresses.Add(new NetworkAddress() { ... });
```